# How to make nVennR diagramm more readable (rstudio)?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I have to make a venn diagram comparing 6 datasets (each of them has over 2500 elements). So I decided to use nVennR package in R, as follows:

```
library(nVennR) 
myV <- plotVenn(list(a = a, b= b, c= c, d= d, e= e, f=f, g= g), nCycles = 2000)
```

And I get this:

[image: venn diagram]

But I would like something more similar to this, where each circle is more defined and more readable:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you took the example from the [vignette](https://mran.microsoft.com/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html). As shown there, you can compact the result by repeating the second command:

```
library(nVennR) 
myV <- plotVenn(list(a = a, b= b, c= c, d= d, e= e, f=f, g= g))
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV) 
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV) 
...
```

After each `myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)` you can inspect the result and decide whether you want to run it further.

Also, you are limiting the number of cycles to 2000. You do not need to do that in general. It is done like that in the vignette because it makes compilation easier on the machines.